# Create response to specific ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column of student final marks (e.g. A1 to A80). In the neighbouring cell (e.g. B1 to B80) I want to create a formula that allows me to do the following:

If below 40% the response should be 988
If between 40 and 50% the response should be 999 
If above 50% the result should be pass

I am not sure what formula to run to so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a formula such as:

```
=IF(A1<40,"988",IF(A1>50,"pass","999"))
```

See the [Excel IF Function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function).

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this.*

[image]

- Enter this Formula in Cell `C2` & fill it Down.

  `=IF(B2<40%,988,IF(AND(B2>=40%,B2<=50%),999,IF(B2>50%,"Pass","")))`

*Adjust cell references as needed.*